# Request-response pattern with worker queues in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ for the following scenario. When a user uses a premium search feature, I send a message via RabbitMQ to one of a few server instances. They run the same routine (DB queries and billing). I want to make sure I don't process the same message more than once.
I've come across [this great tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2012/08/06/150373.aspx) but the exchange type presented in it is "Topic", which does not work for me, because I process the same message more than once.
How can I implement the request-response pattern with worker queues in RabbitMQ so that each message is handled only once and there's load balancing?

Comment: You cannot get "Exactly-Once Delivery" with RabbitMQ (or with anything else distributed, for that matter). It is just [impossible][1].


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

Comment: what's the actual question, here? You've outlined a series of potential problems, but not asked a question. please edit the post to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Anton Gogolev's comment above is correct. You cannot guarantee a message will be processed only once, for many reasons. But, this is often a requirement of systems - to only produce the desired result once.

The way to do that is through [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) - the idea that no matter how many times a given message is processed, it will only make the desired change once.

There are a lot of ways to do this. One simple example is to use a shared database that tracks which messages have been processed. When you receive a message, you check to see if it has been processed already. If not, you process it. If it has, you just ignore it and move on.

In your case, if you are doing request/response and want load balancing, you probably want multiple consumers on the same queue. You could have 2 or 10 or 300 instances of your request handler listening to the same queue, and you won't have too much worry about duplicate processing.

RabbitMQ will send a given message to a single consumer. It will wait for that consumer to say it is done processing, or if the consumer crashes or rejects the message, it will requeue the message for another consumer to try again.

In this way, you will generally have only 1 request handler per request. But it will always be possible for more than one to handle the same message, which is why idempotence is important.

Regarding the use of a topic exchange vs any other type of exchange - it doesn't make much difference. There will always be the possibility of more than one queue receiving the message that you are sending, because you can have multiple queues bound to the same exchange with the same binding keys.

Comment: so is it possible to use RPC with many "Servers" which works like Worker Mode? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: In the above Link they write "If the RPC server is too slow, you can scale up by just running another one. Try running a second rpc_server.py in a new console." So is RPC a kind of Woker Mode just with response?